# How Do Get Tomcat Sessions ID by Java Code Problem

Tags: java, session, tomcat

```java
package zaberp.zab;

import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import javax.servlet.*;

public class SessionListener {

    public static void invalidateAllSessions(ServletContext context) {
        // Get all active sessions
        HttpSession[] sessions = getSessions(context);

        // Invalidate each session
        for (HttpSession session : sessions) {
            session.invalidate();
        }
    }

    private static HttpSession[] getSessions(ServletContext context) {
        // Get the session collection from the servlet context
        Object sessionCollection = context.getAttribute("activeSessions");
        if (sessionCollection instanceof ConcurrentHashMap) {
            ConcurrentHashMap<String, HttpSession> activeSessions = (ConcurrentHashMap<String, HttpSession>) sessionCollection;
            // Convert the collection to an array of HttpSession
            return activeSessions.values().toArray(new HttpSession[0]);
        } else {
            return new HttpSession[0];
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this code this error occurs:

```
11:23:22.967 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.i.c.TargetAuthenticationStrategy - Caching 'basic' auth scheme for http://localhost:8080 Failed to invalidate sessions. Status code: 405
11:23:22.974 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.i.c.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection manager is shutting down
11:23:22.974 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.i.c.DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection - http-outgoing-0: Shutdown connection
11:23:22.974 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.i.c.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager - Connection manager shut down
```

How to resolve this code or problem?

Comment: Study my edit to learn how to format code when posting here.